# Java 8 streams groupby and count multiple properties

Tags: java, java-stream, collectors

I have an object Process that has a date and a boolean error indicator. I want to get a count of total processes and a count of processes with errors for each date. So for example Jun 01 will have counts 2, 1; Jun 02 will have 1, 0 and Jun 03 1, 1. The only way I have been able to do this is streaming twice to get the counts. I have tried implementing a custom collector but haven't been successful. Is there an elegant solution instead of my kludgy method?

```
    final SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
    final List<Process> processes = new ArrayList<>();
    processes.add(new Process(sdf.parse("2016-06-01"), false));
    processes.add(new Process(sdf.parse("2016-06-01"), true));
    processes.add(new Process(sdf.parse("2016-06-02"), false));
    processes.add(new Process(sdf.parse("2016-06-03"), true));

    System.out.println(processes.stream()
          .collect(
                  Collectors.groupingBy(Process::getDate, Collectors.counting()) ));

    System.out.println(processes.stream().filter(order -> order.isHasError())
              .collect(
                      Collectors.groupingBy(Process::getDate, Collectors.counting()) ));

private class Process  {
    private Date date;
    private boolean hasError;

    public Process(Date date, boolean hasError) {
        this.date = date;
        this.hasError = hasError;
    }

    public Date getDate() {
        return date;
    }

    public boolean isHasError() {
        return hasError;
    }
}
```

Code after @glee8e's solution and @Holger's tips

```
Collector<Process, Result, Result> ProcessCollector = Collector.of(
        () -> Result::new,
        (r, p) -> {
            r.increment(0);
            if (p.isHasError()) {
                r.increment(1);
            }
        }, (r1, r2) -> {
            r1.add(0, r2.get(0));
            r1.add(1, r2.get(1));
            return r1;
});

Map<Date, Result> results = Processs.stream().collect(groupingBy(Process::getDate, ProcessCollector));
results.entrySet().stream().sorted(Comparator.comparing(Entry::getKey)).forEach(entry -> System.out
        .println(String.format("date = %s, %s", sdf.format(entry.getKey()), entry.getValue())));



private class Result {

    private AtomicIntegerArray array = new AtomicIntegerArray(2);

    public int get(int index) {
        return array.get(index);
    }

    public void increment(int index) {
        array.getAndIncrement(index);
    }

    public void add(int index, int delta) {
        array.addAndGet(index, delta);
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return String.format("totalProcesses = %d, totalErrors = %d", array.get(0), array.get(1));
    }
}
```

Comment: you can also weaken the type from `List` to `Collection` on your second line.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is preferable that we add a POJO to store the result, or the combiner function may looks a bit obscure. I declared the POJO as public, but you can change it if you think it better to hide it.

```
public class Result {
     public int all, error;
}
```

Main code:

```
// Add it somewhere in this file.
private static final Set <Characteristics> CH_ID = Collections.unmodifiableSet(EnumSet.of(Collector.Characteristics.IDENTITY_FINISH));

//...
// This is main processing code
processes.stream().collect(collectingAndThen(groupingBy(Process::getDate, new Collector<Process, Result, Result> {
            @Override
            public Supplier<Result> supplier() {
                return Result::new;
            }

            @Override
            public BiConsumer<Process, Result> accumlator() {
                return (p, r) -> {
                    r.total++;
                    if (p.isHasError())
                        r.error++;
                };
            }

            @Override
            public BinaryOperator<Result> combiner() {
                return (r1, r2) -> {
                    r1.total += r2.total;
                    r1.error += r2.error;
                    return r1;
                };
            }

            @Override
            public Function<Result, Result> finisher() {
                return Function.identity();
            }

            @Override
            public Set<Characteristics> characteristics() {
                return CH_ID;
            }
})));
```

PS: I assume you have `import static java.util.stream.Collectors`

Comment: Thanks glee8e. Your solution gives the counts of true/false. I was looking to get a total and number of errors. So for Jun 01, it gives me 1, 1 for 1 with error and 1 without. I guess I can sum it up outside the lambda expression to get a total count. But I was really looking to do it within the expression.

Comment: Mind the existence of [`Collector.of(…)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collector.html#of-java.util.function.Supplier-java.util.function.BiConsumer-java.util.function.BinaryOperator-java.util.stream.Collector.Characteristics...-) which allows you to specify the three functions (omitting the identity finisher) without the need for an inner class. You don’t even have to bother specifying the `IDENTITY_FINISH` characteristic, that method will already deduce that from the absence of such a function. But you may consider specifying the `UNORDERED` characteristic…

Comment: I used @Holgers tip to reduce the code a bit. Here's how it looks now

Comment: @Holger Well I was searching for such function in Collectors class but no luck...

Comment: Yeah, it’s in the `interface Collector` rather than the utility `class Collectors`, which is easy to overlook as we are used to search in said utility class only. I remember similar failed searches for a particular convenience method in `Integer`, to learn later that it is in `Math` (or vice versa)…